# iptables / VLAN: interface names

Tags: linux, iptables, opensuse, vlan

I have just started working with VLANs. My memory was VLAN interface names are the interface name plus dot plus the VLAN ID. And that is what `vconfig` offers.

After some (successful) manual tests I wanted to make the configuration with the OS tools (openSUSE in this case). `yast` creates interface names like `vlan5` with no option to change that (I guess that's `vconfig`'s option `VLAN_PLUS_VID`). But that is not a problem. I just renamed the configuration file `ifcfg-vlan5` to `ifcfg-extnets.5`.

**extnets_5 instead of extnets.5 in iptables rules**

I was surprised when I noticed that the openSUSE firewall script creates rules with the interface name `extnets_5` instead of `extnets.5`. This seems not to be an `iptables` limitation. Unfortunately I am at home now and cannot generate test traffic to check which rules match (maybe both do).

If both works: Are there serious arguments (as in: not primarily opinion-based) for or against one of the naming schemes? I prefer `extnets.5` over `vlan5` but `extnets_5` would be OK for me, too. But if `extnets_5` must / should be used with `iptables` then it might be a good idea to use `extnets_5` as an interface name, too?